# Formik & ReduxORM & Yup - validationSchema issue

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup, redux-orm

I'm trying to use a Formik form with a Yup validation schema to edit an entity which come from my ReduxORM session. The validation does not seem to work properly when using a ReduxORM model.

I think it's a Formik issue because I succeed to validate properly my entity using the validate function to manually call Yup:

```
validate={values => CompanyFormSchema.validate(values, { abortEarly: false }).catch(errors => { throw yupToFormErrors(errors) })}
```

(see codesandbox below to try both methods)

Here's a codesendbox which reproduce the issue: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-reduxorm-validationschema-issue-kd95s

I expect the validationSchema attribute to work with ReduxORM model. Have you an idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to extract the `fields` from the entity: `let initialValues = entity._fields;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provide by Christiann (in comment section) is working:
"You need to extract the fields from the entity: 
`let initialValues = entity._fields;`"

Did someone know why there is a difference beetween the schemaValidation behaviour of Formik and the fact to call manually Yup validation schema ?